# How should I handle constraining options in a database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

**[Edited Question]**

[image]

The `List` table has: `rabbit, cat, dog...` etc an infinite list of animals.

The `Animal` table whats to have a restricted list set. So for example. Restrict to rabbit, or cat, or dog. However the restricted list set also has values like `resctrictToAnimalsWithFur`, `restrictToAnimalsStartingWithLetterA` etc etc.

So basically, the `RestrictedList` table set has exactly the items contained in the `List` table + extra values.

I cannot have values in the `RestristedList` table as a FK from the `List` table because it has other values.
But i do not want to duplicate all the values in the `List` table by having them inside the `RestrictedList` table because it seems redundant.

I also cannot just delete the `List` table and only have the `RestrictedList` table because the `List` table is used in other places.

My knowledge on DB is limited on how to solve something like this without duplicating the entire `List` table inside the `RestrictedList` table.

How can i do it? Is this something can has to be solved on the application layer? or can Database solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call that `ExtendedList` rather than `RestrictedList`, because it has more elements...

Anyway, one way in which you can avoid the duplication is by having a table `restrictions` that contains only those entries from `RestrictedList` that are not in `list`.

Then `animal` has two foreign key columns: `list_id`, which points to `list`, and `restriction_id`, which points to `restriction`.

A check constraint makes sure that exactly one of them is set:

```
ALTER TABLE animals ADD CHECK
   (CAST (list_id IS NULL AS integer)
  + CAST (restriction_id IS NULL AS integer) = 1);
```

Comment: In Postgres you could can simplify the check constraint to `check (num_nonnulls(list_id, restriction_id) = 1)`

Comment: In older versions of MySQL, this functionality was not available.